# Is it possible to add a creative commons embed to a Google Doc?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, html

I've written some basic training manuals using Google docs, and would like to release them under a creative commons license. I plan to use the Google drive "Publish" feature to release it to the web, because it is not possible for me to post the document anywhere.(Don't ask why)

The problem comes when I found out that Google docs has removed the option to edit HTML. This means that I can't embed the Creative commons license tag.

I have already tried exporting the document as HTML, adding the Tag, and then uploading it back to Gdocs. It completely ignored the extra HTML. So now I'm stuck.

What can I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and Paste works just fine.

Find your desired license on [CreativeCommons.org](http://creativecommons.org/) and highlight the entirety of the license (not the embed code). Copy the selection to the clipboard and switch to your desired document in Google Drive.

Place your cursor where you want the license to go, preferably at the end of the document, and then Paste from clipboard. It might take a second or so for the picture to load. From there, make sure the license is in the proper place.

And that's about it. Hope this solves "your" problem.

Comment: I think my solution of putting it in the footer, may be a more proper way to do so, so that the license is visible on all pages.

Comment: Thanks for the idea though, I may use that.

Answer (score 5):

There really is no way to do this as it stands right now. What I would suggest is adding a link to the Creative Commons license that you are using in the footer (or header), and that should be good enough.